# line 4, in <module> A = input("Do you have symptoms? ") File "<string>", line 1, in <module> NameError: name 'Yes' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, nameerror

```
A = "Yes"
B = "No"

A = input("Do you have symptoms? ")
B = input("Did you travel in a place with confirmed cases? ")
if A == "Yes" and B == "Yes":
    print("Need to do swab testing. ")
else:
    print("Do a self-quarantine. ")
```

This is a code given my teacher and it is supposed to work apparently :(

Comment: Are you trying to run it in python 2 instead of 3?

Comment: this is code given by a teacher? are you sure considering there is variable shadowing which would indicate someone not familiar with Python

Comment: A = input("Do you have symptoms? ").lower()
B = input("Did you travel in a place with confirmed cases? ").lower()
if A == B == "Yes".lower():
    print("Need to do swab testing. ")
else:
    print("Do a self-quarantine. ")

Comment: what is the error you're getting? you know the inputs are case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

You could delete those two first lines, as they do nothing. That may be what is causing
the error. Tested in PyCharm and both worked with or without the first two lines. Try deleting the lines.